# There are 10 seats numbered 1 through 10. There are 5 boys and 4 girls. The girls must sit in the even numbered seats.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 10 seats numbered 1 through 10. There are 5 boys and 4 girls. The girls must sit in the even numbered seats. How many ways can they sit such that there are no empty seats?

Here is what I tried:

```
  g b g b g b g b b
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

or

```
  b b g b g b g b g
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Therefore the girls can be arranged 4! but in two separate configurations so:
4!*2 accounts for all the ways the girls can sit.

I then used the same logic for boys (it does not state that boys can not sit in the even seats, so a boy can sit in the seat numbered "2"):
5!*2

I multiplied these results together:
48*240=11,520

There is no answer guide for this so I am just trying to see if my thought process is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: If there are $10$ seats and $9$ kids, it's not possible that there are no empty seats.  What exactly does this condition mean?

Comment: The problem does not state that the girls must be seated in consecutive even-numbered seats.  There are five ways to select which even-numbered seat will not have a girl sitting there, so the number of ways of seating the girls is $5 \cdot 4!$.  See vonbrand's answer to your question.

Comment: My apologies - there should be no empty seats BETWEEN people.

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to seat the girls is $4! \binom{5}{4}$ (5 available seats, select 4, permute 4); the number of ways of seating the 5 boys is $5! \binom{6}{5}$ (after seating the girls, there are 6 seats free; select 5 for the boys, permute). In all:

$\begin{align*}
  4! \binom{5}{4} \cdot 5! \binom{6}{5}
     &= 4! \frac{5!}{4! 1!} \cdot 5! \frac{6!}{5! 1!} \\
     &= 5! \cdot 6! \\
     &= 86\,400
\end{align*}$

Comment: Does this satisfy the condition of there not being an empty seat between any of the student? Isn't there a chance that with this permutation/combination that they could be seated bgbg_gbgbb?

Comment: Doesn't this answer assume all seats are equal?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing the seat 1 will not be empty, the number of ways to seat the girls is $4!\cdot\binom{5}{4}$ and the number of ways to seat the boys is $5!$, so in total it is $4!\cdot\binom{5}{4}\cdot5!$.

Supposing now the seat 1 will be empty, you have the same number of ways to seat the boys and since there are only four even seats there are only 4! ways to seat the girls, therefore in total you have $4!\cdot\binom{5}{4}\cdot5!+4!\cdot5!$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  The problem is not symmetric.  It matters whether the first seat is empty or the last seat is empty.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Aren't my two cases exhaustive? If seat 1 is not empty seat 10 is empty, if seat 1 is empty seat 10 is not empty.

Comment: That is true.  However, the cases are not symmetric since there are five seats available to the girls if seat 1 is empty but only four seats are available to the girls if seat 10 is empty.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ah! Yes I see, thank you, I have edited

Comment: Now our answers agree.

Answer (score 2):

The question was poorly worded.

> There are ten seats numbered 1 through 10.  There are five boys and four girls.  The girls must sit in the even-numbered seats.  How many ways can the nine children be seated?

This question has been correctly answered by vonbrand.

*However, it seems the intended question was:*

> There are ten seats numbered 1 through 10.  There are five boys and four girls.  The girls must sit in the even-numbered seats.  How many ways can the nine children be seated if there are no empty seats between people?

If there are no empty seats between people, then the nine children must sit in consecutive seats.  Consequently, either seat 1 is empty or seat 10 is empty.

**Case 1.**  Seat 1 is empty.

Since the girls must be seated in even-numbered seats, there are five seats available to them.  Choose which four of these five seats will be occupied by the girls and arrange them in these seats.  The remaining five seats must be occupied by the five boys. Arrange the boys in these seats.  This can be done in 
$$\binom{5}{4}4!\binom{5}{5}5! = 5 \cdot 4! \cdot 5! = 5!5!$$
ways.

**Case 2.**  Seat 10 is empty.

Since the girls must be seated in even-numbered seats, they must occupy all four of the remaining four even-numbered seats.  Arrange them in these seats.  The five boys must occupy the five odd-numbered seats.  Arrange them in these seats.  This can be done in 
$$\binom{4}{4}4!\binom{5}{5}5! = 4!5!$$
ways.

**Total.**  Since the two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of admissible seating arrangements is 
$$5!5! + 4!5!$$